# Oculus rift, how to add libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, libraries, oculus

Ok, i'm trying to do what is writtent here

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-sensor/

but i have problem with #include

i have no idea where i have to add it, it needs(ovr_capi) much more libraries. where to download it all? how to add everything to this program?

sorry for retared question, but when i'm reading something like this

Initialize LibOVR through ovr_Initialize.
Call ovr_Create and check the return value to see if it succeeded. You can periodically poll for the presence of an HMD with ovr_GetHmdDesc(nullptr).
Call ovr_ConfigureTracking to start sensor input.

i don't know what to do

so, tl;dr
where i can find and how to add all libraries to oculus rift and visual studio

Comment: Did you download the [SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/)?

Comment: yes i did, but i still dont know how to add this libraries to my project

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add the libOVR project to your Visual Studio solution, right click your solution, go to `Add->Existing Project` and browse to `...OculusSDK\LibOVR\Projects\Windows\VS2013\LibOVR`

Reference the project by right clicking your project, go to `Add->Reference` and check the libOVR project.

Next, right click your project, go to `properties->C/C++->General`, under `Additional Include Directories` add the path to `...OculusSDK\LibOVR\Include`